# Retrieving form inside jquery function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms

due to some circunstances of my code, i'm using the following button of a form to call a jquery function:

```
<form id="formElem" name="formElem" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">

....

<button name='enviar_candidatura' id='enviar_candidatura' value='enviar_candidatura' onclick='return false;' type='submit'>Enviar Candidatura</button> 

...
```

The jquery function that is called:

```
$('#enviar_candidatura').bind('click',function(){
    var form = $('#formElem');

    var conta_Duplicates;
    conta_Duplicates=dadosImportantes();
    //alert("Deu");
    var preenchimentoForm=true;
    //alert("Contasssss"+conta1);
    //var eventos=$countEventos;
    var eventos=conta_Duplicates[2];
    //alert("Wiggins"+eventos);
    //var empregos=$countEmpregos;
    var empregos=conta_Duplicates[1];
    //var cursos=$countCursos;
    var cursos=conta_Duplicates[0];

    //alert($countEmpregos);
    /*if($('#formElem').data('errors')){
        preenchimentoForm=false;

        dadosFormularios(form, preenchimentoForm, cursos, empregos, eventos);
        return false;
    }
    else{*/
        dadosFormularios(form, preenchimentoForm, cursos, empregos, eventos);
    //}
});
```

Now what i need is to receive in this function the formElem so that i can define here the action="" of the form and call it using form.action="index.php....".

As you can see in the code above, i tried using

```
var form = $('#formElem');
```

however, that doesn't work, i tried:

```
form.action = 'index.php?pagina=candidaturasB&'+ qstringA;  
form.submit();
```

but without success :/

Comment: You don't happen to have an element with the "action" name do you? Something like `<button name="action">` ... for if you do then whatever they suggest you to do will not work. Just a thought since I don't know what can be a problem since all other suggestions are rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Since `form` is a jQuery object it doesn't have the property `action`. Try this:

```
form.attr('action', 'url');
```

Comment: sorry but not working:

i tried:

var form = $('#formElem');
  form.attr('action', 'index.php');
  form.submit();

but nothing done :(

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 form.attr("action", 'index.php?pagina=candidaturasB&'+ qstringA)
 form.submit();
```

i think there are no method `.action` , so you need to set action as attribute

Comment: sorry but not working:

i tried:

var form = $('#formElem');
  form.attr('action', 'index.php');
  form.submit();

but nothing done :(

Answer (score 0):

`form` is jQuery object, it dosn't have `action` property. You should use `attr` method:

```
form.attr('action', 'index.php?pagina=candidaturasB&'+ qstringA);
```

Comment: sorry but not working:

i tried:

var form = $('#formElem');
  form.attr('action', 'index.php');
  form.submit();

but nothing done :(

Comment: try `form.attr('method', 'post')` before `form.submit()`

Comment: not working :/
can it be because of my button is defined like this:
<button name='enviar_candidatura' id='enviar_candidatura' value='enviar_candidatura' onclick='return false;' type='submit'>Enviar Candidatura</button>

i need him like this that's why i don't change him.

Comment: Are you really sure that this is a main problem? Try submit form from firebug/webinsector console.

Comment: well, if i use this:
window.location.href = 'index.php?pagina=candidaturasB&'+ qstringA;
it works, so i guess this is the main problem :/

Comment: Do you attach your function to `click` signal after DOM is ready (inside `$(document).ready(function{ /* your code */ })`)?

Comment: You should. From jQuery docs: `this is usually the best place to attach all other event handlers and run other jQuery code.`